# Class to Instance Multimap in scala

Tags: scala, collections, multimap

What's the idiomatic way to have associate `Class[T]`s to `List[T]`s? Essentially, I want the equivalent of Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap), but in a Multimap form.

I am uncertain about how Scala's [`mutable.Multimap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap) would fit in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library, but it's quite trivial to implement (using `ClassTag`s instead of `Class` to simplify the API a bit):

```
class ClassToInstanceMultiMap private (private val delegate: Map[ClassTag[_], List[_]]) {
  def addInstance[T](x: T)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = 
    new ClassToInstanceMultiMap(delegate + (ct -> x))

  def getInstances[T](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = delegate.getOrElse(ct, List.empty).asInstanceOf[List[T]]

  // whatever other methods you want
}

object ClassToInstanceMultiMap {
  val empty = new ClassToInstanceMultiMap()
}

// usage
val cimm = ClassToInstanceMultiMap.empty.addInstance(1).addInstance(2).addInstance("a").getInstances[Int]
// returns List(1, 2)
```

Use `TypeTag`s instead of `ClassTag`s if you want to store instances with the same class and different generic type arguments (e.g. `Option[Int]` and `Option[String]`) separately.